# Access Denied when creating forward links on SharePoint 2010 Wiki page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

If I create a forward link on a wiki page as one of the site collection admins and then click on the link I get a pop up saying that the page does not exist and if I want to create it.

When I try to do the same with a user that has Full Control access to the pages list I get access denied. When I temporarily set the user as a site collection admin he can click on the link and also create the new page.

What permission and on what list(s) does a user really need to be able to create these pages when clicking on a forward link?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/8a1ec554-e716-4c6a-92ee-2a79c17c6ec7

The fix to this:

1. Go to Site Actions -> Site Settings ->Modify all site settings
2. Go to Galleries -> Master pages and page layouts
3. From the list toolbar, select Settings -> Document library settings
4. Select permissions for this document library
5. Add 'Restricted Read' access to the required groups.

Once this is done, your users will no longer get the access denied error .